# Is quiting arbitrary mode possible?

Tags: undo, undo-tree-mode

How to exit arbitrary mode x, as it seams for my particular case `undo-tree-mode` there is no `undo-tree-mode` related option for undoing it, it there a general solution?

Answer (score 1):

`undo-tree-mode` is a buffer-local minor mode, so `M-x undo-tree-mode` will toggle it in the current buffer.

Note that if you are in fact using `global-undo-tree-mode` then that is a global minor mode which controls the buffer-local minor mode in all applicable buffers en-masse, and you would want to use `M-x global-undo-tree-mode` to toggle that, if you wanted to disable the buffer-local mode in all applicable buffers.